# Accents with jdk8 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, fonts

I am using JDK8 on Ubuntu, and I am getting troubles with printing document with accent (é,è,à...). (with java print API)  Weird characters are printed instead of these accents.
Is there an issue with JDK8 regarding fonts on Linux?
How can I be sure that all the fonts are well handled with JDK8?

Thanks in advance.

On the non working server I have :

```
 
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

and on the working server i have :

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: weird chars? `Ã`? That'd be a symptom of a character set mismatch. outputting (say) utf8 text into an environment using some other charset (e.g. iso8859)

Comment: It's most likely an encoding rather than a font issue.

Comment: Yes, Ã. The thing is : I am using Jasper Report to print pdfs. It works well on another Ubuntu server, but not on this Ubuntu, I don't know what the differences are between those two servers. On the "working ubuntu" i am using java 1.8.0_25-b17 and on "non working ubuntu" i am using java 1.8.0_45-b14.

Comment: How should we now the differences between those servers? Start by figuring out which Java versions are installed on your servers ...

Comment: using the same encoding and a font that is also available on your dev machine?

Comment: On the "working ubuntu" i am using java 1.8.0_25-b17 and on "non working ubuntu" i am using java 1.8.0_45-b14

Comment: how do I know the encoding and fonts used on the ubuntu server?

Comment: With the `locale` command.

Comment: i have updated my post. on the non working server i have LANGUAGE=  and on the working server i have LANGUAGE=fr_FR

Comment: Now print, from inside a Java program, `Locale.getDefault()` and `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

Comment: I am getting fr_FR and UTF-8